# Turning Weekday into Binary Factor 0 or 1

Tags: r, dummy-variable

```
## Changing Weekday into a categorical variable- Beg/End of Week
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Absenteeism$Weekday)
df$category[Absenteeism$Weekday <= 3] <- "Beginning of Week"
df$category[Absenteeism$Weekday >= 4 ] <- "End of Week"
weekdaycat <- cut(Absenteeism$Weekday, breaks=c(0,3,7), labels=c("Beginning of Week","End of Week"))
summary(weekdaycat)
Absenteeism$Weekday <- as.factor(Absenteeism$Weekday)
summary(Absenteeism$Weekday)
```

New to R and I managed to make my weekday data categorical, but now I need make it binary with beginning of `week = 0` and end of `week = 1`.

Could anyone help me out on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
# Made up weekdays as an example   
Absenteeism <- data.frame(Weekday = (1:10)%%7+1)

# Create a new column with the explicit name
Absenteeism$categoryName = ifelse( Absenteeism$Weekday <= 3, "Beginning of Week", "End of Week")

# Create a new factors column with levels 0 and 1
Absenteeism$category = factor(ifelse( Absenteeism$Weekday <= 3, 0, 1))
```

Results:

```
> Absenteeism
   Weekday      categoryName category
1        2 Beginning of Week        0
2        3 Beginning of Week        0
3        4       End of Week        1
4        5       End of Week        1
5        6       End of Week        1
6        7       End of Week        1
7        1 Beginning of Week        0
8        2 Beginning of Week        0
9        3 Beginning of Week        0
10       4       End of Week        1

> summary(Absenteeism)
    Weekday     categoryName       category
 Min.   :1.00   Length:10          0:5     
 1st Qu.:2.25   Class :character   1:5     
 Median :3.50   Mode  :character           
 Mean   :3.70                              
 3rd Qu.:4.75                              
 Max.   :7.00
```